# Is there a specific term for an accessor method that returns a boolean value?

Tags: object-oriented, terminology

I seem to recall that there is a specific term for an accessor method that returns a Boolean value but it escapes me. For example: typical methods such as:

```
class Example {
    bool isDirty();
    bool hasChildren();
    bool isValid(SomeType obj);
};
```

I will also settle for such a term as applied to a non-member functions.

Comment: While 'is' is generally good enough, it is important to not use 'not' after 'is' otherwise the meaning becomes confusing, for example this obviously bad: isNotGood.

Comment: Yes thanks but what I am really looking for is not a naming convention but rather a term for the whole class of these simple boolean member functions.

Comment: "Accessor methods that return booleans."  Not everything needs a name.

Comment: @Emmad: I think list.isNotEmpty() is more readable than !list.isEmpty()

Comment: @Codism, both are readable, in my case, the 'not' part takes more brain cells to figure :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A function from some type `T` to `Boolean` is usually called a *predicate*, and if you want to make clear that it is a method of an object, i.e. that it takes the implicit `this` argument in addition to its other arguments, then you could call it a *predicate method*. If it takes no other arguments except the implicit `this` argument, then you can call it a *predicate property*.

See for example `Predicate<T>` in .NET and e.g. `javax.sql.rowset.Predicate` or `com.google.common.base.Predicate` in Java.

Comment: +1: Shout out to David Parnas http://www-public.int-evry.fr/~gibson/Teaching/MAT7003/ReadingMaterial/Parnas93.pdf

Comment: why the "no other arguments" thing? i'd say that `isBiggerThan(x)` is a predicate

Comment: Yes predicate is the term I had forgotten... Thanks for refreshing my memory!

Comment: FYI: In Common Lisp the name of predicate functions (should) end with the letter p - so that everyone knows exactly what it is. In languages like Ruby and Clojure the convention is to end the name with a questionmark.

Comment: @Javier: you're right. I think *predicate property* would be a better term for that. I'll change the answer.

Comment: @Torbjørn: i think the question mark convention comes from Scheme.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is simply returning an attribute of the object, I would call it an accessor, since it is simply used to access a private member variable of the object.

If the method performs some kind of computation or contains logic (beyond the possibility of logging or validation), it's simply a method. It's no different than a method that performs any other operations that use the state of the object and return a value that's not a boolean.

If the method preforms some special task, such as checking equality or validity, I might want to refer to it by what it does, such as calling it a "validator method" or "equality method". Those names is a bit shorter than saying "a method that checks the validity of the object" or "a method that checks the equality of this object against another".

Not everything has a special name, though. Call it by what it is.

Answer (score 0):

A switch (which is ambiguous), a flag, a bool, a state...  Nothing I can think of is specific to a getter...

Different environments have different conventions...

Ruby: some_object.is_something?

ObjC: [someObject isSomething]

So I guess I support the "is doctrine"...